# visual studio 2008 - Build issues

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to rebuild a project from the clearcase vob and i get the following error code :

error PRJ0019 .

Any help is very much appreciated ..

thankyou

Comment: Are all the project files in the vob accessible via Windows Explorer?

Comment: yes., they are accessible via windows explorer

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the MSDN page for this error

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzk29wdw(VS.80).aspx

The most likely candidate for causing this problem is a custom build step or script which returns an error code.  You'll need to look at the build output log and see which is the last tool that ran as it's the most likely source of the problem.